# Javascript Select Index value not changing

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html code, and I am trying to set the value of option by selectedIndex. The problem is that the option is still displaying the old value whereas if I do an alert on what was selected it gives me the correct answer.

What am I missing?

```
<select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
    <option value="none">Choose One</option>
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
    <option value="3">c</option>
    <option value="4">d</option>
</select>

<script>
    var HomeLocation = 1;
    document.getElementById("select-choice-1").selectedIndex = HomeLocation;
    alert(document.getElementById("select-choice-1").selectedIndex); // shows 1
</script>
```

Comment: how does it not work? This seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Lyn1mce0/

Comment: What browser is doing this and can you post a JsFiddle replicating the problem?

Comment: its on a tablet browser (android webview)

Comment: I wonder if this is a display bug. Try setting the visibility style to hidden, then an empty string on the next line. This should trigger a redraw of that element.

Comment: Are you maybe using some sort of script that "styles" the select element, e.g. jQuery Mobile, that requires refreshing/updating?

Answer (score 3):

I've had inconsistent behavior with browsers. I usually have to set the `selectedIndex` and set the `selected` property of the `<option>`:

```
var select = document.getElementById("select-choice-1");
select.selectedIndex = 1;
select.options[1].selected = true;
```

Comment: A thousand "Thumbs up"!   Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was using JQuery Mobile and didn't realize that I had to refresh the element. This worked for me:

```
document.getElementById('select-choice-1').value = HomeLocation;
$("#select-choice-1").selectmenu("refresh");
```